# How to copy the key of the previous line, to the key field of the next line in a Key-Value Pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Sample Dataset:

```
$, Claw         "OnCreativity" (2012)  [Himself]

$, Homo         Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>
            Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>

$, Steve        E.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>

$hort, Too      2012 AVN Awards Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself - Musical Guest]
            2012 AVN Red Carpet Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself]
            5th Annual VH1 Hip Hop Honors (2008) (TV)  [Himself]
            American Pimp (1999)  [Too $hort]
```

I have created a Key-Value Pair RDD as  using the following code:

```
To split data: val actorTuple = actor.map(l => l.split("\t"))
 To make KV pair: val actorKV = actorTuple.map(l => (l(0), l(l.length-1))).filter{case(x,y) => y != "" }
```

The Key-Value RDD output on console:

```
Array(($, Claw,"OnCreativity" (2012)  [Himself]), ($, Homo,Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>), ("",Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>), ($, Steve,E.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>).......
```

But, a lot of lines have this "" as key i.e blank (see the RDD output above), because of the nature of dataset, So, I want to have a function that copies the actor of the previous line to this line if it's empty.
How this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

New to Spark and Scala. But perhaps it would be simpler to change your parsing of the lines, and first create a pair RDD with values of type list, eg.

($, Homo, (Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>,Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests] <22>) )

I don't know your data, but perhaps if a line doesn't begin with "$" you append onto the value list.

Then depending on what you want to do, perhaps you could use flatMapValues(func) on the pair RDD described above. This applies a function which returns an iterator to each value of a pair RDD, and for each element returned, produces a key-value entry with the old key.

ADDED:
What format is your input data ("Sample Dataset") in? Is it a text file or .tsv?
You probably want to load the whole file at once. That is, use .wholeTextFiles() rather than .textFile() to load your data. This is because your records are stored across more than one line in the file.

ADDED
I'm not going to download the file, but it seems to me that each record you are interested in begins with "$". 
Spark can work with any of the Hadoop Input formats, so check those to see if there is one which will work for your sample data.

If not, you could write your own Hadoop InputFormat implementation that parses files into records split on this character instead of the default for TextFiles, which is the '\n' character.

Comment: I am also new to Spark and Scala, Would you please give an example for the same in terms of Code/command, and "$" is part of the actor name, which changes, so I can't really use it in normal logic.

Comment: The described logic is not commutative. The RDD elements are partitioned across machines, what if the previous element for a blank key is on a different machine? Also, the RDD data structure is not ordered, I think. I thought it would be simpler to have parsing logic which parses your file into a pair RDD, with the key of the actors name, and a value as a list of all the movies that actor has been in. Any logic which you were hoping to apply within Spark RDD API, I would think you would be able to apply while parsing your file and creating the base RDD.

Comment: I exactly want to have a parsing logic which parses the file into a pair RDD, with the key as actors name, and value as a list of all the movies that actor has been in, but when you parse the Dataset (which can be downloaded from the below link), it is not possible to really extract the list of movies as value & actor as key by just parsing because we have to split lines into fields to make pair. Moreover, its a tab delimited dataset and if we use .wholeTextFiles(), then we will get just 1 line in RDD. I suggest a User defined function to copy the key from previous line if it's empty.

Comment: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/actors.list.gz  link to download the dataset, a text editor like VIM is suggested to be used with this gigantic text file.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the idea xyzzy gave, how about you try this after loading in the file as a string:

```
val actorFileSplit = actorsFile.split("\n\n")
val actorData = sc.parallelize(actorsFileSplit)
val actorDataSplit = actorsData.map(x => x.split("\t+",2).toList).map(line => (line(0), line(1).split("\n\t+").toList))
```

To explain what I'm doing, I start by splitting the string up every time we find a line break. Consecutively I parallelize this into a sparkcontext for mapping functions. Then I split every entry into two parts which is delimited by the first occurance of a number of tabs (one or more). The first part should now be the actor and the second part should still be the string with the movie titles. The second part may once again be split at every new line followed by a number of tabs. This should create a list with all the titles for every actor. The final result is in the form:

```
actorDataSplit = [(String, [String])]
```

Good luck